# Resgatar resultado de service http em outra funçao

Tags: html, angularjs

```
 controllerPrincipalService.getResultado(id).then(function(dados)
    {
        // limpando o retorno
        var p = data.search("{")-1;
        var res = data.substring(76);
        var f = res.search('<');
        dados = data.substring(p, p+f);
        resultado = JSON.parse(dados);
    });

    function pegaResultado(resultado){
        ///trabalhar com o resultado do service a cima.
        console.log(resultado);

    }
```

Como consigo trabalhar com o resultado do meu service acima em uma funcão separada ?
Service esta trazendo um json vi $http.get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa que o callback do get seja executado para trabalhar com o retorno.

O que pode fazer é colocar um watch nessa variavel e adicioná-la ao escopo.

```
$scope.resultado = undefined;
controllerPrincipalService.getResultado(id).then(function(dados)
{
    // limpando o retorno
    var p = data.search("{")-1;
    var res = data.substring(76);
    var f = res.search('<');
    dados = data.substring(p, p+f);
    $scope.resultado = JSON.parse(dados);
});

$scope.$watch('resultado', function(newVal, oldVal){
    ///trabalhar com o resultado do service
    console.log(newVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Armazena o seu resultado num objeto ou variável de escopo raiz (global) e chame uma função que  faça uso deste valor.

```
var globalResultado = null;
controllerPrincipalService.getResultado(id).then(function(dados)
{
    globalResultado = JSON.parse(dados);
    pegaResultado(); //Ou qqr parte do codigo
}

function pegaResultado(){
    ///trabalhar com o resultado do service acima.
    console.log(globalResultado);
}
```

Comment: Também é possível passar o resultado como parâmetro para a função `pegaResultado`, para evitar o uso da variável global e também possíveis conflitos.

Comment: não rolo.. da null

Comment: @LucasMoura, ele chega a entrar no then ? coloca um break point dentro do then e veja se ele trava lá, a principio é pra esntrar. Confere se o lugar que vc está chamando a pegaResultado está chamando antes da resposta ajax.